# React to a mistake in the object of an email

Tags: email

Sorry for my english it's not perfect.
I send an email to 700 people with a mistake in the object.
I don't know how can i react. Is it good to send an other email with a mention (without the mistake is better).

Thanks for you help

Comment: Heavily depends on the mistake you made - was it just a typo or something way more severe?

Comment: it's a mistake of conjugation (thanks french langage)

Comment: What was the mistake?

Comment: It's in french :
"le moment est arrivéE" there isn't a "E"

Comment: What do you mean by "object of an email"? Do you mean the subject line of the email?

Comment: This should probably say "in the _body_ of the email". In formal writing terminology, the subject is called the subject, and the part below the subject is called the body.

Comment: @FlorianAvilez This kind of mistake will probably be seen as a misspelling or typo (missing a letter, or accidentally capitalizing the E). I doubt that a correction is needed, unless there is a chance for confusion (e.g. if you make a mistake on a date or time).

Comment: If French-speaking people sent a follow-up email all the time correcting the spelling mistakes they made in the previous email, the Internet would go down worldwide in a blink of an eye.

Comment: In general, unless it comes from the office of a middle manager or higher, an e-mail sent to everyone is likely to be read by nobody...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the mistake is meaningful (like a wrong date for an event), then it's perfectly ok to send another corrected copy with an apology at the top.

"Sorry, I forgot to include x,y,z"

I get it from time to time in work related mass emails I'm sent.

If it's less severe (a spelling mistake for example), then there's no need to send a correction.

Comment: Yep.  While the mistake like a typo may be a bit harmful to one's reputation, sending a correction will not fix that, and in fact will draw more attention to it.